Syntax error near token on bash script initialising conda
I've been asked to add some BASH script to a server .bashrc file so I can then initialise conda.
When I log into the server, I get the following message:
Last login: Wed Aug 28 16:57:04 2024 from {IP ADDRESS}

-bash: /home/{username}/.bashrc: line 129: syntax error near unexpected token `then' 

-bash: /home/{username}/.bashrc: line 129: `    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then' 


Here's the code:
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

I ran the bash script through shellcheck and it produced this:
Line 126: if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ^-- SC1046 (error): Couldn't find 'fi' for this 'if'. ^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this if expression. Fix to allow more checks. 
Line 129:     if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then ^-- SC1047 (error): Expected 'fi' matching previously mentioned 'if'. >> ^-- SC1072 (error): Unexpected keyword/token. 
Fix any mentioned problems and try again

Can anybody see the error?
Edit:
The /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda file is definitely there, and the /opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh file is also there.

There's a lot of code before what you show; there may be an error there that isn't caught until line 129.

Try https://www.shellcheck.net/ for your complete file

This error did not appear before I added this code so I think it is something defective in the script that I posted.

Could there be an identical line in the output from eval ?

Your file is filled with non-ASCII characters. For example, here's a hexdump of line 7:
$ sed -n 7p foo.sh  | xxd
00000000: e280 afe2 80af e280 af20 6966 205b 202d  ......... if [ -
00000010: 6620 222f 6f70 742f 616e 6163 6f6e 6461  f "/opt/anaconda
00000020: 332f 6574 632f 7072 6f66 696c 652e 642f  3/etc/profile.d/
00000030: 636f 6e64 612e 7368 2220 5d3b 2074 6865  conda.sh" ]; the
00000040: 6e0a                                     n.

The byte sequence e280f is a NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE, and bash doesn't know what to do with that. Replace all the whitespace with actual spaces; the code is otherwise correct.
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2>/dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  "$__conda_setup"
else
  if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
  else
    export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
  fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<


Yes, this was correct! I copied the code from my research group's MS Teams wiki page, which imported these weird characters.
Thanks!

@RobbieMallett Never trust text that was copied from a native app.  Very often it's full of stuff like this.
